# Opa: What is the difference between modules and packages?

Tags: opa

I read [Opa documentation](http://doc.opalang.org/manual), but I did not catch the difference between modules and packages, and how modules or packages are linked to the source layout of an Opa application.

Can someone provide sensible examples on how and when to use modules vs. packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Packages

You can isolate some parts of your application into different `packages`.
For example, you can create 3 packages: model, view and controller.
Just define for examples `package myApp.model` at the beginning of your source files that belong to the model package.

Then, if one of your view file needs the model, just add `import myApp.model` at the beginning of the file.

Instead of writing `package` and `import` in your source file, you can also use a single conf file:

```
myApp.controller:
    import myApp.view
    src/controller.opa

myApp.view:
    import myApp.model
    src/view.opa

myApp.model:
    src/model.opa
```

And then use the --conf compilation option.

### Modules

A module is define this way

```
module MyModule {
   function f(){ void }
}
```

You access to module functions with `MyModule.f()`

### Modules inside a Package

So if you have a package `model` with a module `MyModule` defined in it, and you want to access to it from outside, you'll write:

```
import myApp.model
MyModule.f()
```

**Update**: read messages below, they provide other useful information.

Comment: So, modules and packages are two ways to organize opa source code, but when to use modules, and when to use packages. Can functions be private to a module or to a package? Does a package or module allows to expose functions or variables?

Comment: packages make sense in the compilation process (e.g. you can compile them separately). You have to import a package to use it. Functions inside a module are public by default, but you can change their visibility with the `private` directive.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement Cedrics answer:

*Packages are a basic compilation unit*. If a package nor any of the packages it depends on changes then it does not need to be recompiled. For smaller projects it may be ok not to use packages, which is equivalent to putting everything in one single package. For bigger projects you'll usually want to split the project into several packages to benefit from separate compilation.

*Modules mainly provide a namespace for related definitions*. You can have multiple modules in one package.

Opa does not impose any filename restrictions. You can have multiple modules in one file and their names are not related to the name of the file. There is also no imposed relation between package name and the place of the file in the source directory tree (although using conventions certainly makes sense here). Obviously one file belongs to a single package.

Answer (score 0):

Basically packages are always used to include values and functions that are defined in another file. (With the exception of those, that are defined in the standard library.) Hence it can separate code parts from each other or in other words structure you code into different parts. Their way of usage is already explained in Cédrics answer. Packages offer no abstraction as the complete code is always included with an `import`.

Modules on the other hand offer abstraction. With modules it is possible to define values and functions that are only used *inside* the module and not visible from the outside. This makes it possible to hide parts of the implementation to the user of the module and offer well defined *interfaces* to the outside. This concept makes it easier to change specific implementation parts without breaking code where the module is used. This is a very important concept in the design of programs.